# Cannot assign ipv4 address in instance google cloud sql

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-console

I have tried to delete and add new instances to try it again, but it keeps on showing me the following message when I try to modify the authorised networks of an MySql instance:

```
"You don't have permission to edit authorized networks on this instance."
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an authorisation or a graphical issue, are you the project owner of the project?

However I tried to "replicate" the issue and I visualise the very same message, but it let me modify the authorised networks, therefore it could be merely a graphical issue. (I am the project owner)

I have checked with different projects facing the very same problem therefore I raised a [public issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/73470196) and I will push an inspection.

You can star and follow the public issue in order to get the updates.

**UPDATE**

The issue has been solved and the fixed rolled out.

> Disclaimer: I work for Google Cloud Platform Support

Comment: Yes I am the owner of the project and it still displays the message when i assign ip address...and i went to IAM and adding new role of my email to Owner, Editor,Cloud SQL Admin, Cloud SQL Client and Service Account Admin for me to hopefully be authorized to assign the ip but the mssg is still there.

Comment: Yes, I visualise it as well, but it should be merely a graphical issue, for example if I try to add an authorised network I can do it. If you can't, you can try again with an incognito window.

Comment: The backline team contacted me back and informed me that the fixed should have been released.